Comma Usage in "At COMPANY-NAME we are committed to providing the highest level of customer service."
Should there be a comma after COMPANY-NAME in the following sentence:

At COMPANY-NAME we are committed to providing the highest level of customer service.


It's optional. Comma usage is normally a matter of opinion; there are lots of similar questions although I can't find an identical one.

A comma is neither mandated nor forbidden here. But including one has the pragmatic value of indicating measured, accommodating speech (rather than brusqueness) ... but the trade-off is that it appears slightly less clinical, professional.

You don’t need a comma for very, very short introductory phrases, unless hilarity or confusion would otherwise ensue... At Least we are committed to providing the highest level of customer service.

Commas are often encouraged after long introductory phrases (“long” is, of course, subjective) to aid with parsing the sentence. The phrase in your example is rather short, so it’s really just up to you. You could argue that adding a comma might evoke a pause, which could serve to emphasize what precedes it. But nothing is required.
